# Validating date format with Zend_validator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate

How can I validate the date format (dd-mm-yyyy) using zend_validate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply use the [Date validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.date) (`Zend_Validate_Date`).

Eg

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Date(array(
    'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    'locale' => $yourLocale
);
```

Comment: @Ludwig Considering this answer was posted in 2011 (well before ZF2), I don't find that surprising at all.

Comment: But it is still worth mentioning it to save other ZF2 users the time to test ist

Comment: @Ludwig This question is tagged [tag:zend-framework], not [tag:zend-framework2]. Combine that with the complete lack of namespaces (`Zend_Validate_Date` vs `Zend\Validate\Date`) and I really don't think it's too much to assume a ZF2 dev is going to bother with this answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment to validate against an exact date format in [zendframework2](/questions/tagged/zendframework2) (see [ZF2 Issue #4763](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4763)) but you can add an extra regex validator (see example here) or write a custom validator to handle this (see [zf2](/questions/tagged/zf2) Issue).

```
use Zend\Validator\Date;
use Zend\Validator\Regex;

$validator = new Date(array(
    'format' => 'd-m-Y',
));
$validator2 = new Regex(array(
    'pattern' => '%[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}%',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did this,

```
$DateFormat = new \Zend\Validator\Date(array('format' => 'Y-m-d'));

    if(!($DateFormat->isValid($somedate))){
    //if not valid do something 

}else{

//do something else
}
```

i forgot to mention that this is for Zend 2.0